# Update a Picker (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5, swiftui-navigationlink

I would like to present to the user a picker choice after having selected it with an AddView.
The EditView launched by a DetailView shows me the Textfield full but the Picker is still empty although I've selected an item before.

I've created two models (both are identifiable, codable, equatable, hashable) which are related to 2 arrays:

- Grocery(model) ---> groceries (array)
- Food(model) ----> shoppingChart (array)

My aim is to add a new grocery by assigning a name and by selecting a food stored in the shoppingChart from the Picker.
I used the AddView to store the grocery and the EditButton inside the DetailView to edit the data stored.
I used a Toggle "if" to activate the Picker.

Here is the code:

```
class Food: Hashable, Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {

var id : UUID = UUID()
var name : String

init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}

static func == (lhs: Food, rhs: Food) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
hasher.combine(name)
}

enum CodinKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodinKeys.self)
    self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodinKeys.self)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
}
}

class Grocery: Hashable, Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {

var id : UUID = UUID()
var name : String
var monday : String
var tuesday : String
var wednesday : String

init(name: String, monday: String, tuesday: String, wednesday: String) {
self.name = name
self.monday = monday
self.tuesday = tuesday
self.wednesday = wednesday
}

static func == (lhs: Grocery, rhs: Grocery) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
hasher.combine(name)
hasher.combine(monday)
hasher.combine(tuesday)
hasher.combine(wednesday)
}

enum CodinKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
    case monday
    case tuesday
    case wednesday
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodinKeys.self)
    self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    self.monday = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .monday)
    self.tuesday = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .tuesday)
    self.wednesday = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .wednesday)
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodinKeys.self)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(monday, forKey: .monday)
    try container.encode(tuesday, forKey: .tuesday)
    try container.encode(wednesday, forKey: .wednesday)
}
}

import SwiftUI
import Combine

class FoodManager: ObservableObject {

@Published var shoppingChart: [Food] = []

init() {

        let milk = Food(name: "Milk")
        let coffee = Food(name: "Coffee")

        shoppingChart.append(milk)
        shoppingChart.append(coffee)        
}


func newFood(name: String) {
    let food = Food(name: name)
    shoppingChart.insert(food, at: 0)
}

func editFood(id: UUID, name: String) {

    if let food = (shoppingChart.filter { $0.id.uuidString == id.uuidString }).first {
        food.name = name
    }
}
}

class GroceryManager: ObservableObject {

@Published var groceries: [Grocery] = []

init() {

        let grocery_1 = Grocery(name: "Walmart", monday: "", tuesday: "", wednesday: "")
        let grocery_2 = Grocery(name: "Whole Foods", monday: "", tuesday: "", wednesday: "")

        groceries.append(grocery_1)
        groceries.append(grocery_2)
}


func newGrocery(name: String, monday: String, tuesday: String, wednesday: String) {
    let grocery = Grocery(name: name, monday: monday, tuesday: tuesday, wednesday: wednesday)
    groceries.insert(grocery, at: 0)
}

func editGrocery(id: UUID, name: String, monday: String, tuesday: String, wednesday: String)     {

    if let grocery = (groceries.filter { $0.id.uuidString == id.uuidString }).first {
        grocery.name = name
        grocery.monday = monday
        grocery.tuesday = tuesday
        grocery.wednesday = wednesday
    }
}
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var food_dm : FoodManager
@ObservedObject var grocery_dm : GroceryManager

@State var isAddGroceryViewOpened = false
@State var isEditOpened = false
@State var fieldtext : String = ""
var grocery : Grocery?

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.grocery_dm.groceries, id:\.self) { grocery in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(grocery_dm: self.grocery_dm, food_dm: self.food_dm, grocery: grocery))
                    {
                        HStack {
                            Text(grocery.name)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            buttonAdd
        }

    }
}

var buttonAdd: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.isAddGroceryViewOpened.toggle()
    }) {
        Text("Add")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isAddGroceryViewOpened) {
        AddGroceryView(food_dm: self.food_dm, grocery_dm: self.grocery_dm, isAddGroceryViewOpened: self.$isAddGroceryViewOpened)
    }
}
}
```

---

```
struct DetailView: View {

@ObservedObject var grocery_dm : GroceryManager
@ObservedObject var food_dm : FoodManager

var grocery: Grocery

@State var isAddGroceryViewOpened = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
    Text("Grocery: \(grocery.name)")
    Text("Foods: \(grocery.monday)")
    buttonEdit
    }
}

var buttonEdit: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.isAddGroceryViewOpened = true
    }) {
        Text("Edit")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$isAddGroceryViewOpened) {
        AddGroceryView(food_dm: self.food_dm, grocery_dm: self.grocery_dm, isAddGroceryViewOpened: self.$isAddGroceryViewOpened, grocery: self.grocery)
    }
}
}
```

---

```
struct AddGroceryView: View {

@ObservedObject var food_dm : FoodManager
@ObservedObject var grocery_dm : GroceryManager

@State var selectFood = ""
@State var grocery_name : String = ""

@Binding var isAddGroceryViewOpened : Bool

var grocery : Grocery?

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Write a grocery", text: $grocery_name)
                monday_view(food_dm: self.food_dm, PickFood_String: self.$selectFood)
            }
            saveButton
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        if let groceryOk = self.grocery {
            self.selectFood = groceryOk.monday
            self.grocery_name = groceryOk.name
        }
    }        
}

var saveButton: some View {
Button(action: {

    self.salva()
    self.isAddGroceryViewOpened = false
    })
     {
    Text("Save")
}
}

func salva() {
if !self.grocery_name.isEmpty && !self.selectFood.isEmpty {
        if let groceryOk = self.grocery {
            self.grocery_dm.editGrocery(id: groceryOk.id, name: self.grocery_name, monday: self.selectFood, tuesday: "", wednesday: "")
    } else {
            self.grocery_dm.newGrocery(name: self.grocery_name, monday: self.selectFood, tuesday: "", wednesday: "")
    }
        }
    self.isAddGroceryViewOpened = false
}
}

struct monday_view: View {
@State var isOn = false
@ObservedObject var food_dm : FoodManager
@Binding var PickFood_String: String
@State private var queryType: Int = 0

var body: some View {

    let binding = Binding<Int>(
        get: { self.queryType },
        set: {
            self.queryType = $0
            self.PickFood_String = self.food_dm.shoppingChart[self.queryType].name
    })

    return
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Monday")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

                Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
                    Text("")
                    if(self.isOn) {
                        Picker(selection: binding, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(self.food_dm.shoppingChart.indices) { foods in
                                Text(self.food_dm.shoppingChart[foods].name).tag(foods)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
     }
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
struct monday_view: View {
    @State var isOn = false
    @ObservedObject var food_dm : FoodManager
    @Binding var PickFood_String: String
    @State private var queryType: Int = 0

    var body: some View {

        let binding = Binding<Int>(
            get: { self.queryType },
            set: {
                self.queryType = $0
                self.PickFood_String = self.food_dm.shoppingChart[self.queryType].name
        })

        return
            VStack {

                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Monday")
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

                        Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
                            Text("")

                        }
                    }
                    if(self.isOn) {
                        Picker(selection: binding, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(self.food_dm.shoppingChart.indices, id: \.self) { foods in

                                Text(self.food_dm.shoppingChart[foods].name).tag(foods)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing.. if I tap on the Button "Edit", I see only the Textfield valorized... The Picker is still blank although I've selected a food before